# How to increase the space of database in sql 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a domain in godaddy window server and its totaly full . I want to increase the space of my database or add a new database with the same domain .
How can I do that.?

Comment: Contact the hosting company...

Comment: This is not a programming question

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a pure vendor issue